# Is it possible to set dependencies for a folder using require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is it possible to set dependencies for an entire folder using `require.js`?

I know that you can use the shim configuration to set dependencies for a file:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'plugin/backbone/xyz': {
            deps: ['lib/backbone'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

In the above example I define the dependencies for the plugin backbone/xyz, but I would like to define the dependencies for all backbone plugins:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'plugin/backbone/': { // I would like to specify a folder here but it doesn't work.
            deps: ['lib/backbone'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});
```

---

I think that I once found a gist about it on GitHub, but I can't seem to find it again.

---

**To clarify:** This isn't about requiring an entire folder, but setting dependencies for it - What all files in the folder needs before they are ready to initialize, each and one of them. It would be accomplished by adding shims for all the files, but I would like to only have to add that shim once for the entire folder:

```
shim: {
    'lib/backbone': {
        exports: 'Backbone' // <- No use of .noConflict() so all plugins can be required and export Backbone as well.
    },
    'plugin/backbone/a': {
        deps: ['lib/backbone'], // <- Require backbone
        exports: 'Backbone' // <- Export backbone
    },
    // Same requirement and folder for these files:
    'plugin/backbone/b': {
        deps: ['lib/backbone'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'plugin/backbone/c': {
        deps: ['lib/backbone'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a great feature. Especially if I'm using something like Angular, which has tons of controllers, services, etc. Would be great to just say my "app" folder depends on angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot easily create a wildcard to add dependencies to all files under a folder from the configuration itself.  You can however create a loop before the config and add whichever dependencies you want.

```
var config = {
    shim: {
        'plugin/backbone/xyz': {
            deps: ['lib/dependency'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
};
for(var shim in config.shim) {
    if(shim.indexOf('plugin/backbone/') == 0) {
        if(config.shim[shim].deps == null) {
            config.shim[shim].deps = [];
        }
        config.shim[shim].deps.push('lib/backbone');
    }
}
require.config(config);
```

This is the only way I can think of without having to override one of require's functions yourself.  Not elegant, I will admit, but it will do the job.

Comment: You should remove the `each` after `for`: `for ( var shim in config.shim ) {}`

Comment: Ah, sorry, was thinking actionscript.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@J_A_X's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17800915/887539)

You can make an array of files that should share the same dependencies and create the shim dynamically:

```
var config = { shim: { /*...*/ } }

var plugins = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    plugin_shim = {
        deps: ['lib/backbone'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    };  

plugins.forEach(function(file) {
    config.shim['plugin/backbone/' + file] = plugin_shim;
});

require.config(config);
```

But this wouldn't work very well if someone would minuglify using [`r.js`](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/)